# WSO2 ESB custom properties for Smooks mediator

Tags: wso2, smooks, wso2-esb

I need to use some configuration settings to transform message with Smooks mediator. For example I want to inject a base URL into attribute value of outgoing xml during transformation.

In Java I'd do it by adding beans to ExecutionContext. Looking at SmooksMediator code I do not see this. Can I do it somehow or I should extend and recompile SmooksMediator to supply properties form MessageContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the input as the Smooks mediator we can feed only one stream from the ESB. So if you want to transform a message by injecting a property, you can't achieve it with the smooks mediator.

Use XSLT mediator for this [1]. When configuring the XSLT mediator you can define properties to be passed into the transformation.

ex:

```
 <xslt key="orderTransformer">
   <property expression="get-property('name')" name="name"/>
   <property expression="get-property('email')" name="email"/>
</xslt>
```

Then inside the XSLT you can define the two properties as below,

```
<xsl:param name="email"/>
<xsl:param name="name"/>
```

and use them appropraitely as $email and $name in templates.

```
<ns1:email>
        <xsl:value-of select="$email"/>
    </ns1:email>
    <ns1:name>
        <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
    </ns1:name>
```

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/XSLT+Mediator

Comment: As alternative we used Enrich mediator to 'glue' together 2 xml documents and process them in Smooks...

Comment: Great! That also would do.

Answer (score 0):

The whole configuration details of Smooks mediator can be found from [1].

Else you can go for a custom mediator to perform your exact task. Detail on custom mediator can be found from [2].

[1]. http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2011/06/perform-data-mapping-smooks-editor-wso2-carbon-studio

[2]. http://maninda.blogspot.com/2012/11/writing-custom-mediator-for-wso2-esb.html

Thank you,
Dharshana